# Add data in nested form to a json object from extjs form

Tags: json, extjs, hashmap, nested

I have a table coded in extjs, inside a panel, where the user types in information in the 2 columns of the table. I wish to add this data inside a json object which is inside the main json object.

e.g. : Table 'stats' has 2 fields x and y. 
I wish my json looks like :

```
{
    ....
    stats: [
        {
            x : ..,
            y : ..
        },
        {
            x : ..,
            y : ..
        }
        // this goes on depending upon the number of rows of entries in the table
    ]
}
```

Please advice how do I implement this. If I take a HashMap with String as key and `List<String>` as value and then write

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to implement something like below which gives you this JSON string, which you can parse in js file to render extjs form :

```
{"stats":[{"y":"y0","x":"x0"},{"y":"y1","x":"x1"},{"y":"y2","x":"x2"},{"y":"y3","x":"x3"},{"y":"y4","x":"x4"}]}
```

Code :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JSONObject element = new JSONObject();
        element.put("x", "x" + i);
        element.put("y", "y" + i);
        array.put(element);
    }

    obj.put("stats", array);

    System.out.println(obj);
```